# how to check for backspace(delete) keyPress in react native (iOS)

Tags: javascript, react-native, backspace

I want to fire a function when the user hit backspace in a textbox. I have searched on stack overflow and React Native docs but there is not a relevant answer.
basically, I don't know whats the keyname for backspace

```
      <TextInput
          onChangeText = {e => {
          e === 'BackSpace' ? alert('delete') : alert(e)
       }}/>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`onChangeText` **only** sends the updated text value. It does not send any other information such as keypress. `onChange` sends much more information, `onChangeText` is just for convenience.

You could use `onKeyPress`

```
<TextInput
  onKeyPress={({ nativeEvent }) => {
    nativeEvent.key === 'Backspace' ? //do action : //other action
  }}
/>
```

You cannot use `alert` however, you must use [`Alert`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert#docsNav) in `react-native` which has a different API.

However it might be easier to just use `onChangeText` depending on what you're trying to accomplish. If the text value sent is shorter than the currently controlled text value, you can handle whatever backspace code you're using and manage the text input value in one place.

Answer (score -1):

As suggested [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onkeypress) you could try something like this :

```
<TextInput
     onKeyPress = {e => {
     e.keyCode === 'Backspace' ? alert('delete') : alert(e)
}}/>
```

Comment: what does keyDown do?

Comment: It is an event triggered when a user press down a key inside an input. Google is your friend here.

Comment: sorry man, but that's not the same for iOS, or at least it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Maybe you should try the onKeyPress then (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onkeypress)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182871/discussion-between-rguerin-and-syed-bcc).